# Storing personal information in cookies

Tags: privacy, cookies

I'm trying to do a simple display integration between two websites.

One on:

```
domain.com
```

and another on:

```
subdomain.domain.com
```

All I want to do is show a **"Hello John, Return to Client Area"** message.

I'm looking for some advice on whether you think it's acceptable to store information such as a first name and e-mail address in a cookie?

I need first name for "Hello [Name]" and email for a gravatar. I could pre md5 the gravatar, or add the gravatar url to the cookie, however its a similar premise either way.

This information will be useless, so changing it won't be able to do anything malicious.

I know i could simply create a [logged in = true] cookie that shows return to user area. However i feel the other way gives a better illustration of being logged in.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I hope by `domain.com` and `subdomain.domain.com` you do not mean you are using HTTP in which case the cookies are highly exposed and manipulated on an attacker's will. I hope also -in case you are not using HTTPS- the services of your website are not crucial (not e-commercial, for instance).

As a general good security practice, **never store private information in cookies **. If a client of your website uses his/her main email address to login then for sure they wouldn't like to see it used by a third party (spams) thanks to your website (in case you use, for example, Google AdSence). Add to this a set of common famous cookies' vulnerabilities such as  [cross-site cooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_cooking) or simply [cookie theft](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24633/cookie-theft).  An email address is important data -in my case, I wrote it encoded on my profile. I definitely advise you not to use email within cookies.

**Solution:**

As everything else, sessions are not safe for 100%, but still it is better to generated unique session identifier in the cookie, and  **store everything else on your server** instead. This pretty much eliminates common threats such as [cookie poisoning](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/16076/cookie-poisoning). And as for cookies, do not store  any data in the session pertaining to access credentials (in your case, the client's email ?)